# How to do the Cupertino "stacked" full dialog transition effect in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to replicate the same behaviour as native iOS when navigating to certain pages, like in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKa2d.jpg) from the Clock app.

The closest thing I have found is the [CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition-class.html) class, but does not replicate the stacked effect that iOS does.

Is there any widget that already does that? If not, how can I replicate the same effect in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) that does exactly what I was seeking. Although it's not exactly the same as native iOS, I will leave it here in case anyone else needs it.